# I am trying to add self signed certificates for my istio envoy proxy. But I am unsure about the openssl commands to be used

Tags: kubernetes, openssl, ssl-certificate, istio, envoyproxy

I have used the following commands to generate the root certificate and the actual certificate.It says that the certificate is not authorized to sign other certificates.Am I missing something? I am new to these tls certificates

Root certificate:

```
openssl genrsa -out root-key.pem 2048
openssl req -new -key root-key.pem -subj "/C=IN/ST=RJ/CN=cluster.local/emailAddress=test@foo.com" -out ca.csr
openssl x509 -req -in ca.csr -signkey root-key.pem -CAcreateserial  -out root-cert.pem -days 1000
```

Actual certificate:

```
openssl genrsa -out ca-key.pem 2048
openssl req -new -key ca-key.pem -subj `"/C=IN/ST=RJ/CN=cluster.local/emailAddress=test@foo.com"` -out ca-user-admin.csr
openssl x509 -req -in ca-user-admin.csr -CA root-cert.pem -CAkey root-key.pem -CAcreateserial  -out ca-cert.pem -days 1000
```

And for the cert-chain.pem, I am doing **cp root-cert.pem cert-chain.pem**

```
echo "" >> cert-chain.pem 
cat ca-cert.pem >> cert-chain.pem
```

I am referring these steps after I created these https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/security/cert-management/plugin-ca-cert/

Please help me out with this. Am I missing something here ? Or should I get my certificates signed by some other trusted CA ?

Comment: Istio automatically generates certificate.Is there any reason for you generating it?

Comment: So I wanted to have my own custom certs, All the communication between the envoy proxies should be using these certificates

Comment: I also referred to this , https://discuss.istio.io/t/custom-ca-on-istio-1-6-2/7161 , Hard Luck , Couldn't get that working

Comment: failed to create discovery service: failed to create CA: failed to create an istiod CA: certificate is not authorized to sign other certificates
This is the error I am getting

Comment: reopen this issue https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/16337 or create a new issue

Comment: Created a new issue https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/25872

Comment: Did you create a secret from your self signed certificate and then install istio with that as mentioned [here](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/security/cert-management/plugin-ca-cert/#plugging-in-existing-certificates-and-key)?

Comment: Yes, I did create the secret !! Even after that, I am getting the same issue !!

Comment: @jt97 are the above-mentioned OpenSSL commands correct?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to generate the certificates using these commands. I am not sure if this is the correct way to do them. After following these steps my istiod was able to sign the workloads with my own CA. After this, I followed the steps given in this page https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/security/cert-management/plugin-ca-cert/

```
CONFIG="
  [req]
  distinguished_name=dn
  [ dn ]
  [ ext ]
  basicConstraints=CA:TRUE,pathlen:0
  "
openssl req -config <(echo "$CONFIG") -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes \
  -subj "/C=IN/O=dEVOPS/OU=DevOps/ST=RJ/CN=cluster.local/emailAddress=test@gmail.com" -x509 -extensions ext -keyout root-key.pem -out root-cert.pem
cp root-cert.pem ca-cert.pem
cp root-key.pem ca-key.pem
cp ca-cert.pem cert-chain.pem
```